# Load an HTML page into an HTML frame using Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

As of title, I'm trying to load an HTML page into an HTML frame using Flask.

When I open the frameset.html page on a Firefox tab (substituting {{src}} with index.html of course), the frameset behaves correctly.
However, whenever I run the python code, the loaded HTML page is correctly divided between the frames, but there is no trace of the index.html page in any of it.

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)
page = 'index.html'

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('frameset.html', src=page)

app.run()
```

**frameset.html**

```
<html>
<frameset rows="10%,80%,*">
    <frame src=''>
        <frameset cols='20%,40%,40%'>
            <frame src=''>
                <frame src='{{src}}'>
                    <frame src='' name="output">
        </frameset>
        <frame src=''>
</frameset>

</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <style type="text/css">
        .container {
            max-width: 500px;
            padding-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="genostats.html" target="output">GENO stats</a>

</html>
```

How can I solve this problem? The code I wrote here is just to test the functionality of the framesets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create another route at `@app.route('index.html')` rendering `index.html` the template, make sure the `index.html` file is in the templates folder

like this:

```
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

resources need to be served from either the `templates folder` or the `static folder` in flask, you can't have a resource and have it automatically served as that would be incredibly insecure, since any user then will have access to your entire server by simply changing the link.

Comment: Wouldn't this spawn a new page instead of placing it in the third frame, as I would like to do? All of the resources are already put in the templates folder.

Comment: 1. you probably want to use an iframe instead of a frame
2. I don't think so, why don't you try and tell me!

Comment: Thank you! I haven't had the possibility to test it before, but I just did and everything now works flawlessy. I'm not too much of an expert on HTML, should I add any more attributes to iframe if I were to change frame to iframe, or can it be considered ok without any further modifications?

Comment: honestly, I'm not even sure, I'm extremely new to web-dev and right now, as I've read html5 does not support frames, I don't think I'll even consider using an frame.

basically I started off using iframes, I'm clueless about how frames work