# Using python3 and flask to get URL from another server

Tags: python, flask

Using  this stackoverflow append ([Load an HTML page into an HTML frame using Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54240948/load-an-html-page-into-an-html-frame-using-flask/54242820)) as a guide and being new to Flask I was wondering how one goes about getting another URL (say ---> https://www.afl.com.au/ as an example) to display in a frame (or iframe) within my own application that uses Flask and Python3 and **is running locally (i.e. on localhost)** on my own PC ?

I have a feeling I would have to use Apache or CURL or ...? and call it to service the request ?
If so, then how to direct the content from the other web site to the Frame (or iFrame) in my application ?

OK - I apologise, for what I am not sure, but given the lack of responses I figure I must have committed some cardinal sin I am unaware of ...I have been digging/researching (see below) ...I can get closer to the goal but the contents of the second URL (compjour.org) re using "embed" don't always work in practice, so I was wondering if anyone could throw some light on the why is that so?

Further work reveals that I can do it ...here is my sample code - it works for the URL 'http://www.bom.gov.au/wa/observations/index.shtml' but not he second one for youtube. (note that file frameset2.html is in the same Dir as the app.py code. ) and frameset2 code is as follows:

```
<html><iframe src='{{src}}' width="853" height="480" frameborder="0"  allowfullscreen></iframe></html>
```

Also I came across this append http://www.compjour.org/lessons/flask-single-page/simple-youtube-viewing-flask-app/
but what they say about embed doesn't seem to work (not every time anyway) on you tube anymore.

Any ideas please ?

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
# page = 'index.html'
# page = 'http://www.bom.gov.au/wa/observations/index.shtml'
page = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?' + 'v=Ov7-FC0KHQA&feature=youtu.be'

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\blah blah ") #not the real dir of course
                                 # all code is in same dir

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('frameset2.html', src=page)


app.run()
```

frameset2

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Youtube URL is not working correctly is because they have specifically disabled the ability to display Youtube in a frame.
This is done by sending the HTTP Header `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` with the response from youtube. There is no way around this unless you install some sort of browser extension (BOM on the other hand does not seem to care if you display their information in a frame).

You can verify this by checking the console in your browser to see if any errors are displayed during loading of the page.

Comment: Thanks Dan - mystery solved - I had a hunch that the UT people had done something

Comment: @dra42841 I think you could put your own answer to your post. That would help others who are encountering the similar issue.